# Decimal read in does not change

Tags: r

I try to read in a .csv file with, example, such a column:

[image: img]

These values are meant like they are representing thousands of hours, not two or three hours and so on.
When I try to change the reading in options through

`read.csv(file, sep = ";, dec = ".")` nothing changes. It doesn't matter what I define, `dec = "."` or `dec = ","` it will always keep these numbers above.

Comment: Why not multiply the column by 1000 after you read it in?

Comment: I solved this with a workaround by setting the numerical columns in Excel, which were on data type "General" to "numeric", within Excel.
I hate Excel..

Comment: @AllanCameron Well, that's too easy..    yeah, would have been simpler and faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
library(readr)
df <- read_csv('data.csv', locale = locale(grouping_mark = "."))
df
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 1
  `X-ray`
    <dbl>
1    2771
2    3783
3    1267
4    7798
```

As you can see, the values are now thousands.

Comment: thank you, but I receive "Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  unused argument (locale = list(list(c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"), c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"), c("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"), c("AM", "PM")), "%AD", "%AT", ",", ".", "UTC", "UTF-8"))" ?

Comment: this is probably because it messes with other columns in the .csv file?

Comment: @Ben, Yes that is true. I wasn't aware that you had multiple columns looking at your image.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for that. I didn't know it would cause another issue :)

Answer (score 2):

An elegant way (in my opinion) is to create a new class, which you then use in the reading process.

This way, you stay flexible when your data is (really) messed up and the decimal/thousand separator is not equal over all (numeric) columns.

```
# Define a new class of numbers
setClass("newNumbers")
# Define substitution of dots to nothing
setAs("character", "newNumbers", function(from) as.numeric(gsub("\\.", "", from)))
# Now read
str(data.table::fread( "test \n 1.235 \n 1.265", colClasses = "newNumbers"))
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  1 variable:
#   $ test: num  1235 1265
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by Quinten will work; however, it's worth adding that function which is designed to process numbers with a grouping mark is `col_number`.

```r
with(asNamespace("readr"),
     read_delim(
       I("X-ray hours\n---\n2.771\n3.778\n3,21\n"),
       delim = ";",
       col_names = c("x_ray_hours"),
       col_types = cols(x_ray_hours = col_number()),
       na = c("---"),
       skip = 1
     ))
```

There is no need to define specific locale to handle this specific case only. Also locale setting will apply to the whole data and intention in this case to handle only that specific column. From docs:

> `?readr::parse_number`
>
> This drops any non-numeric characters before or after the first number.

Also if the columns use `;` as a separator, `read_delim` is more appropriate.